# How do you stop a foreground service from its notification?

Tags: java, android

I've found some sample code online that I've tried replicating but it seems like it doesn't actually stop the service, only the notification. Because of this, when I call startForegroundService() again, onCreate() isn't called and therefore startForeground() is never called and the app crashes shortly afterwards.

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanList.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Intent stop_intent = new Intent(this, NewService.class);
    //stop_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    stop_intent.setAction("STOP_SERVICE");
    PendingIntent pending_stop = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, stop_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("AdamService")
            .setContentText("Running")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_notification, "Kill Service", pending_stop);

    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    int notificationId = 234;
    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    //notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    startForeground(notificationId, builder.build());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand Called");
    if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("STOP_SERVICE"))
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Killing Service");
        //notificationManager.cancel(234);
        reset();
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to return START_STICKY instead of super.onStartCommand?

Comment: I tried that, didn't seem to fix anything.